# Measuring time for WPF Databinding processing

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, performance

I am to evaluate several competing frameworks for WPF components which process large amounts of data (100000 entries and up). Thus, I need to time the real performance. As all our software is strictly MVVM/Data binding driven, that is the test environment I use. What I need is to find a way to measure time between my view model sets some value and the end of rendering by the view. Visually it takes several seconds, but I'd like to have exact measurements.

I can of course start a stopwatch when setting the property, but how do I find out that the rendering is ready? Is there an event or something for this?

Comment: Use a profiler, that's the best way. I personnaly use dotTrace for that kind of perfromance measures. http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. But, I have several dozens different tests with different data sets, multiplied by several frameworks under test. Would love to automate that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it won't give you exact measures, but an easy way to do it is using the Dispatcher

```
var sw = new StopWatch();
sw.Start();
//Set value and raise property changed
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
   sw.Stop();

}), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
```

The Loaded priority is just below the Render priority, so the stopwatch will be stopped after the view has been rendered.

Comment: Works like a charm. More then enough for precision I need.